# List .Add is not propagated to list variable

Tags: .net, wcf

I create a list to store some token objects

```
public class PSService : IPSService
{
    private List<Token> validTokens = new List<Token>();
```

Then I call a method through SoapUI to add a token to that list.

```
private bool RegisterToken(Token token)
    {
        validTokens.Add(token);

        //this loop successfully prints the list contents.
        foreach (Token validToken in validTokens)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("registeredToken: " + validToken);
        }
            return true;
    }
```

(unrelated code removed for clarity)

Then I have another method which reads the content of that list.
But when i call it trough SoapUI (after the register call) I do not get the expected response

```
public bool PostProduct(Token auth, Product item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("input: " + auth);
            //Console.WriteLine("validtoks: "+ validTokens.First()); 
            foreach (Token tok in validTokens)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid: " + tok);
                Console.WriteLine("Deze zijn equal: " + tok.Equals(auth));
            }

            return false;
        }
```

(again removed unrelated code)

the (commented) validTokens.First() gives a "List does not contain elements" error.
The loop does not execute (since there are no elements)

Methods are all in the same class.

I think I am creating a copy of validTokens within the RegisterToken context, but how do I avoid that?

Comment: How do you register `PSService`? Are you sure that you are working with the same instance of it?

Comment: The code is in a WCF Service Library, i have a separate comand line application which instantiates the service like this:             

using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PSService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service ready");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

Comment: Then problem is somewhere outside provided code. Does `RegisterToken` and `PostProduct` called in the same request? Should `validTokens` be preserved between requests? Does not have much experience with WCF but would assume it can create multiple instances of  `PSService`.

Comment: No they are called in separate requests, i am looking into if PSService can be instantiated more then once. But yes, it should be preserved, which is why i put it outside of the methods. I figured that should have done it, but aparently i am wrong in that asumption. I am learning WCF so it is all new to me.

Comment: If it should be preserved then(if you don't want to save it to database) the declare property as `static` and use `ConcurrentDictionary` or `ConcurrentBag` at least .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to @Guru stron 's comment i looked into the multiple instances posibility.

```
public class PSService : IPSService
{
    private static List<Token> validTokens = new List<Token>();
```

making a variable static persists it across all instances of a service.
it now works correctly.

Comment: Since it is WCF your collection can be accessed from different threads, please use some synchronization to access it or use suitable concurrent collection.

Comment: Yes, I have since changed the implementation to a Concurent Dictionary, thanks for the help.